# Matlab: how to add a method that reverses a buffer stack?

Tags: matlab, class, buffer, handle

How can I add a method that reverses a Buffer with the following declaration to the CStack implementation:
function reverse(obj) 
The method should reverse the order of the elements in the stack.

For example, if the stack initially contained the following elements: 
16 5 9 4 2 ? ? ? 
Then, after applying the reverse function, it should contain the elements: 
2 4 9 5 16 ? ? ?

```
classdef CStack < handle
        %   s = CStack(c);  c is a cell, and could be omitted
        %   s.size()        returns the numbre of elements
        %   s.isempty()     returns true when the stack is empty
        %   s.empty()       deletes the content of the stack
        %   s.push(el)      pushes el to the top of stack
        %   s.pop()         pops out the top of the stack, and returns the element
        %   s.top()         returns the top element of the stack
        %   s.remove()      removes all the elements in the stack
        %   s.content()     returns all the data of the stack (in the form of a cell with size [s.size(), 1]
        %
        % Copyright: zhang@zhiqiang.org, 2010.
        % url: http://zhiqiang.org/blog/it/matlab-data-structures.html

        properties (Access = private)
            buffer;
            cur;
            capacity;
        end

        methods

            function obj = CStack(c)
                if nargin >= 1 && iscell(c)
                    obj.buffer = c(:);
                    obj.cur = numel(c);
                    obj.capacity = obj.cur;
                elseif nargin >= 1
                    obj.buffer = cell(100, 1);
                    obj.cur = 1;
                    obj.capacity =100;
                    obj.buffer{1} = c;
                else
                    obj.buffer = cell(100, 1);
                    obj.capacity = 100;
                    obj.cur = 0;
                end
            end

            function s = size(obj)
                s = obj.cur;
            end

            function remove(obj)
                obj.cur = 0;
            end

            function b = empty(obj)
                b = obj.cur;
                obj.cur = 0;
            end

            function b = isempty(obj)
                b = ~logical(obj.cur);
            end

            function push(obj, el)
                if obj.cur >= obj.capacity
                    obj.buffer(obj.capacity+1:2*obj.capacity) = cell(obj.capacity, 1);
                    obj.capacity = 2*obj.capacity;
                end
                obj.cur = obj.cur + 1;
                obj.buffer{obj.cur} = el;
            end

            function el = top(obj)
                if obj.cur == 0
                    el = [];
                    warning('CStack:No_Data', 'trying to get top element of an emtpy stack');
                else
                    el = obj.buffer{obj.cur};
                end
            end

            function el = pop(obj)
                if obj.cur == 0
                    el = [];
                    warning('CStack:No_Data', 'trying to pop element of an emtpy stack');
                else
                    el = obj.buffer{obj.cur};
                    obj.cur = obj.cur - 1;
                end
            end

            function disp(obj)
                if obj.cur
                    for i = 1:obj.cur
                        disp([num2str(i) '-th element of the stack:']);
                        disp(obj.buffer{i});
                    end
                else
                    disp('The stack is empty');
                end
            end

            function c = content(obj)
                c = obj.buffer(1:obj.cur);
            end


              function reverse(obj)


              obj.buffer(1:obj.capacity) = fliplr(obj.buffer(1:obj.capacity));


              end
        end 
    end

I would appreciate any tips on how to fix my code. Thanks in advance.
```

checking the code with:

```
s1 = CStack({1,2,3,'GGG'}); 
s1.reverse(); disp('----'); disp(s1); 
s1.push(5);  
s1.reverse(); disp('----'); disp(s1); 
s1.empty(); disp('----'); 
s1.reverse(); disp(s1);
```

expected output:

```
---- 1-th element of the stack:
 GGG 
2-th element of the stack:     
 3 
3-th element of the stack:      
2
4-th element of the stack: 
     1
 ---- 1-th element of the stack:    
  5
 2-th element of the stack:
      1 
3-th element of the stack:  
    2 
4-th element of the stack:     
 3 
5-th element of the stack: 
GGG 
---- The stack is empty
```

Comment: You’re almost there! `obj.capacity:-1:1`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, use flip left-right (`fliplr`) and basic indexing.

```
a=[1:10];
length=5;
a(1:length)=fliplr(a(1:length));
```

I assumed you want to only flip some of the elements (due to your example containing trailing ?? ?? ??), but if you want to flip the entire array, you just need

```
a=fliplr(a);
```

I'll leave how to add that to your class to you.

**NOTE**: this works for horizontal arrays/cells. Obviously change `fliplr` for its vertical version `flipud` if you have vertical arrays.

Comment: function reverse(obj)
             
          obj.buffer(1:obj.capacity)= fliplr(obj.buffer(1:obj.capacity));
          
          end

Comment: @topzeramail it works for me when I add values to the properties, so you will need to be more specific. Perhaps add an example of how you are testing it.

Comment: I edited it with the full code and the testing template.

Comment: Thank you, I did not get the expected output. I got  :                                                                     1-th element of the stack:
     1

2-th element of the stack:
     2

3-th element of the stack:
     3

4-th element of the stack:
GGG
----
1-th element of the stack:
     1

2-th element of the stack:
     2

3-th element of the stack:
     3

4-th element of the stack:
GGG
5-th element of the stack:
     5

Comment: @topzeramail thanks, that is exactly what you showed. I can replicate, using your code, the correct output, by changing it to `flipud`, as I said. You keep moving the question. Please do an effort to understand what I am trying to do and modify it in a way that helps your code. I am not going to write your class for you